# How to remove '\r\n' from my text file using batch file or curl?

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a `curl` command:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "*****messsage_request******" https://******/api/ > "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"
```

The output of this is in a JSON format (I get this output in one line):

```
[{"title_name":"abc","title_number":"1","title_des":"this is the title \r\nof the new song\r\n abc","add_comments":"Yes, I like \r\nthis song"},{"title_name":"efgh","title_number":"2","title_des":"\r\nthis is the title of the new song efgh","add_comments":"would\r\n there be parking spot\r\n"}]
```

I want to remove the `\r\n` from it. The `\r\n` could be anywhere.

I tried to replace:

```
-d
```

With:

```
--data-binary
```

But it didn't work.

I could use batch file or I think curl has a way to filter but I am not sure since I have not used both much.

Comment: No, it didn't work out. It just echoed this C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json and also \r\n. Didnt made any change

Comment: Hi, I dont want to be rude but it didnt work out. I tried all 3 atleast 2 times. Maybe you are in the right direction, but is not getting the right way. Btw, in 2nd code, the file is created and instantly gets deleted. I tried to change it but didnt work well. Some problem with the 3rd code too

Comment: In the curl command, there is '&' inside the post request. (Sorry cannot post the actual information)

Comment: I have tried, but didnt work as '!' is still causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```bat
@echo off

(curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "*****messsage_request******" https://******/api/)>"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json) do (
    set "line=%%A"
)
echo %line:\r\n=%
```

Something more general here (adapted from above):

```bat
@echo off

(curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "*****messsage_request******" https://******/api/)>"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"

for /F "delims=" %%A IN (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    call echo %line:\r\n=%
)
```

This, will `echo` output to cmd, but the file will remain **with** `\r\n`. To also modify the file, use:

```bat
@echo off

(curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "*****messsage_request******" https://******/api/)>"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('type "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"') do (
    set "line=%%A"
    call echo %line:\r\n=%>"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"
)
```

However, the suggested way, is as follows:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "*****messsage_request******" https://******/api/') do (
    set "line=%%A"
    call echo %line:\r\n=%>"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\outputfile.json"
)
```

which is much sorter.

The `%line:\r\n=%` means to search in variable `line` (content of file) the string `\r\n` and replace it (`=`) with nothing, so just remove it.

*Note: You have mentioned that your `curl` command contains `&`. Replace it with `^&` to make it work!*

Comment: The second code works properly but if the json file contains '!' then it does not work. For example: 
[{"title_name":"abc","title_number":"1","title_des":"this is the title! \r\nof the new song\r\n abc","add_comments":"Yes, I like \r\nthis song"}]

Then output i get is [{"title_name":"abc","title_number":"1","title_des":"this is the title"Yes, I like this song"}]

Comment: I think it has to do something with this: setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Comment: It gave the same result. Didn't work. Creates problem when there is exclamation mark !

Answer (score 0):

IMO PowerShell is much better suited to process Json output, especially multiline data

```
## Q:\Test\2019\02\14\SO_54696007.ps1
# $Json = curl.exe --% -H "Accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "*****messsage_request******" https://******/api/

# simulateed input
$Json = '[{"title_name":"abc","title_number":"1","title_des":"this is the title \r\nof the new song\r\n abc","add_comments":"Yes, I like \r\nthis song"},{"title_name":"efgh","title_number":"2","title_des":"\r\nthis is the title of the new song efgh","add_comments":"would\r\n there be parking spot\r\n"}]'

$Table = $JSon | ConvertFrom-Json
$Table | Out-GridView
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable batch solution would manipulate strings within environment variable strings. But the maximum variable length that batch can process is around 8191 characters. It is conceivable that the CURL output could exceed that length, so pure batch is probably not a good option.

There are a number of scripting languages native to Windows that can easily process text of arbitrary length, such as JScript, VBScript, PowerShell.

There are also readily available 3rd party command line tools that can manipulate text, including Windows ports of unix utilities. For example sed can be found for Windows.

I would use my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processor](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) utility, since I always have it handy and it is simple and convenient :-) It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe required.

```
curl --YourArguments | jrepl \r\n "" /L >"yourOutputFile.json"
```

or

```
curl --YourArguments | jrepl \r\n "" /L /O "yourOutputFile.json"
```

The `/L` option treats the search term as a string literal, which is what you want.

If you want to first capture the curl output, and then post-process with JREPL, then

```
curl --YourArguments >"yourOutputFile.json"
call jrepl \r\n "" /L /F "yourOutputFile.json" /O -
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Unix-y solution, how about

```
curl ... things | awk "{printf("\""%s"\"",$0)}' >output
```

(DOS quoting gleaned from [Gawk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/DOS-Quoting.html); I hope it's still current.)